# Need help displaying specific text based on woocommerce tag

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

`

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'bbloomer_show_free_shipping_loop', 5 );
 
function bbloomer_show_free_shipping_loop() {
   echo '<p class="shop-badge">Orders over $99 ship FREE</p>';
}
```

`

The above code is the code that displays the text under the price information on the store page.

It works fine on my site.

I want to expose this text based on product tag.

For example, you want to expose the text only for products with the "event" tag.

I hope you help

I don't know how to code. Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'bbloomer_show_free_shipping_loop', 5 );
 
function bbloomer_show_free_shipping_loop() {
global $product;
   $product_id = $product->get_id();
  if ( has_term( 'event', 'product_tag', $product_id ) ) {
   echo '<p class="shop-badge">Orders over $99 ship FREE</p>';
  }
}
```

Please let me know if you find any issues

Comment: Thank you so much.
Works great.
you are like my god
I wish you only happiness.
Regards

Comment: I am happy that code worked for you. Thanks. Appreciated

Comment: If answer is correct, please mark it as correct. This will help other users to quick follow the answer